# routing table and (iproute2 vs net-tools)

Tags: iproute

I have the following routing table:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enx6a58445c5d43
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx6a58445c5d43
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enx6a58445c5d43
192.168.57.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet1
```

When I use the following command I get error:

```
# ip route add 192.168.42.0/24 via  192.168.57.1 dev vboxnet1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

But When I use from net-tools I don't get any error:

```
# route add -net 192.168.42.0/24 gw   192.168.57.1 dev vboxnet1
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enx6a58445c5d43
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx6a58445c5d43
192.168.42.0    192.168.57.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 vboxnet1 ####add here
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enx6a58445c5d43
192.168.57.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet1
```

Question is : How can I add by iproute2?

Comment: You probably need to do `ip route replace 192.168.42.0/24 via  192.168.57.1 dev vboxnet1`

Comment: Ok, Thanks, But my question is conceptual: Why when can'y find my ip via `ip r get my_ip` I get same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have network address 192.168.42.0/24 in your routing table.
So you have to:

```
ip route replace 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.57.1 dev vboxnet1
```

Or

```
ip route del 192.168.42.0/24 
ip route add 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.57.1 dev vboxnet1
```